# Struts 2: how to send JSON to action

Tags: java, model-view-controller, json, struts2

How to send Json to action, on Struts2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a [short tutorial](http://www.jgeppert.com/2010/06/how-to-parse-a-json-object-when-using-multisearch-for-jqgrid-with-java/) related to the struts2 grid plugin, I think you can adopt it also without grid plugin.